# satisfying if statement with all nodes of enumerateChildNodesWithName

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, velocity, enumeration

I'm building a sprite kit game and in my update method I have a few if statements checking node velocities.  The issue I'm having is with the statement checking if the x and y velocities are equal to 0.  In the game there are 3 orbs which I'm checking velocities of.  Right now this if statement is satisfied if it finds at least 1 orb with x and y velocities equal to 0 - but I want it to execute only if ALL the orbs satisfy the statement.

How would I go about doing this?  Thanks in advance!

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    centerOrbs()
    orbLayer.enumerateChildNodesWithName("player", usingBlock: { node, _ in
        if let orb = node as? Orb {
            orb.checkObjects()
            let rotation1 = orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dy
            let rotation2 = orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dx
            orb.zRotation = atan2(rotation1!, rotation2!)

            if (orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dx == 0 && orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dy == 0) {
                self.compareOrbPositions()
            }

            if (orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dx != 0 || orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dy != 0) {
                self.waitForOrbsToStop()
            }
        }
    })
    let count = String(moveCount)
    moveCountLabel.text = NSString(string: "Moves: \(count)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update a boolean variable in the enumeration loop and check the outcome
after all nodes have been enumerated:

```
var allVelocitiesAreZero = true
orbLayer.enumerateChildNodesWithName("player", usingBlock: { node, stop in
    // ...
    if (orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dx != 0 || orb.physicsBody?.velocity.dy != 0) {
        allVelocitiesAreZero = false
        stop.memory = true
    }
})

if allVelocitiesAreZero {
    // ...
}
```

The `stop.memory = true` causes the enumeration to stop because in that case the
remaining iterations would not change the outcome anymore.